# How can one change the value of a knob with the computer keyboard in FL Studio?

Tags: daw, fl-studio

Many parameters may be changed through knobs in FL Studio. One way to change the knob value is to drag-and-drop with the computer mouse. Is there any way to change the knob value with the computer keyboard?

Example of knobs in FL Studio:

[image]

Comment: You sound like the type of power-user who would use a tracker-style program, just saying. Also there are separate MIDI controllers you can hook up, so that the knob is physically on your table.

Comment: If you feel discomfortable clicking the mouse and holding it while dragging (I do sometimes), you could use a less-precise alternative. In FL Studio 12 you could mouse-over the knob and when turning the mouse wheel in certain direction, you will see the change applied to the knob.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Thanks, this is great to know as one could then map keyboard shortcuts or some voice command with the mouse wheel down and up.